# How to call a function after an asynchronous for loop of Object values finished executing

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, asynchronous

I want to call a function after an asynchronous for loop iterating through values of an Javascript object finishes executing. I have the following code

```
for (course in courses) {
    var url = '...' + courses[course];

    request(url, (function (course) {
        return function (err, resp, body) {
            $ = cheerio.load(body);

            //Some code for which I use object values    
        };
    })(course));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in vanilla JS, but I recommend the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module, which is the most popular library for handling async code in Node.js. For example, with [`async.each`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async#each):

```
var async = require('async');

var courseIds = Object.keys(courses);

// Function for handling each course.
function perCourse(courseId, callback) {
    var course = courses[courseId];

    // do something with each course.
    callback();
}

async.each(courseIds, perCourse, function (err) {
    // Executed after each course has been processed.
});
```

If you want to use a result from each iteration, then [`async.map`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async#map) is similar, but passes an array of results to the second argument of the callback.

If you prefer vanilla JS, then this will work in place of `async.each`:

```
function each(list, func, callback) {
    // Avoid emptying the original list.
    var listCopy = list.slice(0);

    // Consumes the list an element at a time from the left.
    // If you are concerned with overhead in using the shift
    // you can accomplish the same with an iterator.
    function doOne(err) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        if (listCopy.length === 0) {
            return callback();
        }

        var thisElem = listCopy.shift();

        func(thisElem, doOne);
    }

    doOne();
}
```

(taken from a [gist](https://gist.github.com/qubyte/4705801) I wrote a while back)

I strongly suggest that you use the async library however. Async is fiddly to write, and functions like `async.auto` are brilliant.

Comment: Where is that written? This seems odd advice. In any case, the async library (the second most depended upon in npm) is so ubiquitous that it seems to be a reasonable exception.

Comment: This has the node.js tag, which is more specific and takes precedence.

Comment: Browserify is not mentioned. In any case, this appears to be using the request module, which [cannot be used with browserify](https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/455).

Comment: There is a vanilla alternative `each` function in the answer now.

Comment: Using node.js and refusing to use/learn the ansyc lib seems incredibly silly.

Comment: It is. Even if you don't use jQuery, the chances are that a front end engineer will have to read and understand an external codebase that does use jQuery. That analogy is true of Node. You can go vanilla (not clever, NIH syndrome) but you will at some point have to read and understand code that involves async.

Comment: @Mark S. Everitt The pure JS is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I like to understand what is going on rather than it being obfuscated in some library. I'm not saying "don't" or "won't", just that the pure JS gives a better understanding.

Comment: I'm on board with that. Ultimately you need to know what's going on. This is actually why I like async and loathe promises. I can write any function from async, but writing a promise from scratch is a nightmare.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt, +1 for the answer, but disagree about promises. I'd go with promises. In a year or two from now I'll probably be using a normal JavaScript `for` loop with `yield promise` inside for this. It's already possible today: http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/how-yield-will-transform-node

Comment: I use generators with the [co](https://www.npmjs.org/package/co) library for async in [my own experiments](https://github.com/qubyte/blog). No promises are necessary to use generators for asynchronous function management, as thunks work just as well and are far simpler. Like async, writing a basic version of co is easy. The real argument for promises is that they are slated to be part of ES6. That does not make them any less complex though.

Comment: And you got a debate thread for free too! :P Handling async code is a contentious issue to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

A possible simple JS solution would be to do something like this.

```js
var courses = {
  lorum: 'fee',
  ipsum: 'fy',
  selum: 'foe'
};

var keys = Object.keys(courses);
var waiting = keys.length;

function completedAll() {
  console.log('completed all');
}

function callOnCourseComplete(course, func) {
  console.log('completed', course);
  waiting -= 1;
  if (!waiting) {
    func();
  }
}

var delay = 10000;
keys.forEach(function(course) {
  var url = '...' + courses[course];
  console.log('request', url);
  setTimeout((function(closureCourse) {
    return function( /* err, resp, body */ ) {
      // Some code for which I use object values
      callOnCourseComplete(closureCourse, completedAll);
    };
  }(course)), (delay /= 2));
});
```

Update: Probably a better Javascript solution would be to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s

```js
const courses = {
  lorum: 'fee',
  ipsum: 'fy',
  selum: 'foe',
};

function completedAll() {
  console.log('completed all');
}

function callOnCourseComplete(courseName) {
  console.log('completed', courseName);
}

let delay = 10000;
const arrayOfPromises = Object.keys(courses).map(courseName => (
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = `...${courses[courseName]}`;
      console.log('request', url);
      setTimeout((err, resp, body) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }

        // Some code for which I use object values
        resolve(courseName);
      }, (delay /= 2));
    }))
  .then(callOnCourseComplete));

Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)
  .then(completedAll)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for. The question is for a callback *after* the loop. i.e. after all iterations have not completed, not after each iteration.

Comment: The wording of the question is quite confusing for me, even after reading it multiple times I am not 100% certain what is being asked.

Comment: @Mark S. Everitt Do you believe that this is now a correct understanding of the question?

Comment: That has a function that runs after the async loop calls have all called back, so it looks like it does the job, if my interpretation of the question was correct. There's no need to make the waiting object though. You could just measure the length of the keys array an decrement it in callOnComplete, firing func when it his zero.

Comment: Yes, that is a sensible suggestion. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Sorry for the phrasing, my bad. But @Xotic750 you understood it perfectly. Your solution worked, but the delay function kind of makes it a bit "unclean". Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXTv7/8/) for async loop without delay.

Comment: I just had the delay (which is halved on each call) in there so that the completions came back in a different order to the requests, like could happen with a real async request. :)