# for loop with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have some trouble managing the flow control in node.js. Here is my problem:

I have an array of objects, and I want to do something with every object (for example write it to file or send somewhere via network...). I want to be sure that every object is processed and after that i wanna continue with some other function. In this example `processObj()` function is 
iterating through every object and write that object to file. Where should I put callback call to be sure that callback function of `processObj()` will be executed after all objects are written to the file?

```
//Array of n objects...
var objArray=[{},{},{},{}];

//process every Object, for example write object to file...

function proccessObj(obj,callback){
    var myObj = obj;
    for(var i=0;i<myObj.length;i++){
        //process single object, for example:
        ws.appendFile('file.txt',myObj[i],function(){
            //callback
        })
    }
    callback() // <-- If i put callback here it will be executed before callbacks of  ws.apendFile

}

//execute function
processObj(objArray,function{

    //Do something after  all objects in array are saved to file...
});
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_semaphore you should look into the async module on npm or better yet - use promises which are a better and stronger (but a tad harder to grasp) abstraction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a function after an asynchronous for loop of Object values finished executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921723/how-to-call-a-function-after-an-asynchronous-for-loop-of-object-values-finished)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter.

```
function proccessObj(obj,callback){
    var myObj = obj;
    var pending = myObj.length;  // keep track of done items
    for(var i=0;i<myObj.length;i++){
        //process single object, for example:
        ws.appendFile('file.txt',myObj[i],function(){ 
            pending--;
            if (pending == 0) {
                callback(); // This callback will be executed after all the items are done
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this function doesn't run multiple times at the same time, I suggest you do this :

```
function proccessObj(obj,callback){
    var myObj = obj;
    for(var i=0;i<myObj.length;i++){
        //process single object, for example:
        ws.appendFile('file.txt',myObj[i],function(){
            //callback
            if(!--i) callback();
        })
    }
}
```

Inside the `appendFile` callback, the variable `i` will be equal to `myObj.length`. Tehn, when the callback is done, it will decrease the variable `i` by one and once it reach 0, the callback will proc.

Comment: This is dangerous.  If `ws.appendFile` runs synchronously at any point (which could be reasonable behavior if, for example, `myObj[i]` was an empty string) you will manipulate `i` partway through the loop.  Just use an extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
It seems that a asynchronous semaphore is a good solution. But again I have to ask if this is good way of implementing a very simple semaphore, and is it a good solution for my problem:

```
function processObj(obj,callback){
        var semaphore = 0;
        var myObj = obj;
        for(var i=0;i<myObj.length;i++){
            //process single object, for example:
            semaphore++;
            ws.appendFile('file.txt',myObj[i],function(){
                semaphore--;
                if(semaphore===0){
                    callback();
                }
            })
        }
}
```

It works good in my case, and it doesn't require any modules, but I'm not sure is it a good way for solving this problem.